Не изменяется управление при перевыборе Unity (Input Action Asset)
второй день пытаюсь понять, в чем проблема - по какой-то причине не переназначаются кнопки управления. Причем в списке на UI панели с управлением кнопка меняется, а фактически управление остается прежним. Таким образом переназначается кнопка:
inputActionAsset.FindActionMap(actionMap.name).ChangeBinding(index)
.WithPath($"<Keyboard>/{((KeyCode)i).ToString().ToLower()}");

А так происходит сохранение и загрузка:
PlayerPrefs.SetString("BindingSave", inputActionAsset.SaveBindingOverridesAsJson());
inputActionAsset.LoadBindingOverridesFromJson(PlayerPrefs.GetString("BindingSave"));

Сохранение корректно загружается, но, аналогично вышеописанному, само управление не меняется. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Мб потому что не сохраняете? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html

@АлександрДаниловский, дело в том, что все загружается корректно и отображается, но на управление не влияет

Ситуация, которую вы описываете, может быть связана с отсутствие вызова Enable() после загрузки настроек.
После загрузки новых биндингов с помощью inputActionAsset.LoadBindingOverridesFromJson(), вам нужно убедиться, что вы вызываете метод Enable() для каждого ActionMap. Это нужно для того, чтобы убедиться, что обновленные настройки применились. Пример:
inputActionAsset.LoadBindingOverridesFromJson(PlayerPrefs.GetString("BindingSave"));
inputActionAsset.FindActionMap("YourActionMap").Enable();
Так же, убедитесь, что вы загружаете настройки биндингов до того, как начинается игровая сессия, чтобы все биндинги были корректно применены до того, как игрок начнет взаимодействовать с игрой.
